# $\ell$-isogeny graphs over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, isogeny

I have a lot of questions about the following paragraph ([reference](https://defeo.lu/wurzburg/wurzburg.pdf)), most of which are probably relatively easy to answer.

[image]

1. What even is an $\mathbb F_q$-rational morphism? Is it a morphism over $\mathbb F_q$?
2. If that's what it means, why is $\phi$ $\mathbb F_q$-rational iff $\pi(G) = G$?
3. Why "Formally, [...]", what does that mean?
4. $E[\ell] \cong (\mathbb Z / \ell \mathbb Z )^{\oplus 2}$ ($\ell$ is assumed to be prime). Why does $\pi$ act on $E[\ell]$ like an element of $GL_2(\mathbb F_\ell)$?
5. Why is the order of $\pi$ in $GL_2(\mathbb F_\ell)$ the degree of the smallest extension of $\mathbb F_q$ where all $\ell$-isogenies of $E$ are defined?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) A morphism $\phi : \mathbb{P}^N \to \mathbb{P}^M$ is given by $M + 1$ homogeneous degree $d$ polynomials in $\bar{k}[x_0,...,x_{N}]$. If these polynomials are in $k[x_0,...,x_n]$ (possibly after scaling by $\lambda \in \bar{k}^*$) then $\phi$ is said to be $k$-rational. Equivalently if $\sigma(\phi(P)) = \phi(\sigma(P))$ for all $\sigma \in G_k$.

(2) An isogeny is determined by its kernel. It is a theorem that $\phi$ is definied over $k$ if and only if $Ker(\phi)$ is $G_k$-stable. Since $G_{\mathbb{F}_q}$ is topologically generated by the Frobenius this occurs if and only if $G = Ker(\phi)$ is stable under $\pi$.

(4) An element of $G_k$ acts as an automorphism of $E[l]$. Fixing a $\mathbb{F}_l$-basis for $E[l]$ the automorphisms are just elements of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_l)$.

(5) Note $\pi^k$ acts trivially on $E[l]$ if and only $\pi^k$ stablises all cyclic subgroups of $E[l]$. By the same argument as (2) this occurs if and only if all isogenies are defined over the fixed field of (the closure of) ${\langle \pi^k \rangle} \subset G_k$. This fixed field is $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$, which has degree $k$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: 1. I couldn't find this definition. Do you have a reference?
 2. Thanks, I found this in Silvermann, Remark III.4.13.2
 3. No idea what he means by "Formally"?
 5. Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @rollover If you're following Silverman, then the definition is in I.3 (the first definition). "Formally" is used all the time by authors to just say "We now make the informal discussion preceding this comment more formal"

Comment: The notation "k-rational" isn't mentioned there either, but maybe I could have guessed..

Comment: @rollover $k$-rational and defined over $k$ are synonyms